# How do I calculate the base of an exponent if I know the result and what it was raised to?

Tags: exponentiation

If I know the outcome of a value being raised to a certain power, is it possible to know what the original base was?

Example:

```
x ^ 0.25 = 2.5045
```

What's the proper way to calculate x?

Comment: Raise both sides to the power $4$.

Comment: Raise it to the reciprical power:  $x^n = b$ so $x = (x^n)^{1/n} = b^{1/n}$.  So $x^{1/4} =2.5045 \implies $x = 2.5045^4$.

Answer (score 7):

The proper way to do $x^b = a$ is to both sides to $1/b$.

$x = (x^b)^{1/b} = a^{1/b}$.

So $x = (x^{.25})^{1/.25} = 2.5045^{1/.25} = 2.5045^4 = 39.3445102866600625$.

Answer (score 0):

They way to generally do this would be that you take the logarithm of both sides of the equation. Then you would have:

$$ \log(x ^{0,25} ) = \log(2.5045) $$

Then, since $$ \log(a^b) = b * \log(a) $$

you end up with $$ 0,25 * \log(x) = \log(2.5045) $$

which implies that $$ 10^{(\log(2.5045) / 0,25)} = x $$
by the definition of the logarithm

Comment: But $10^{\log(2.5045)/0.25} = 2.5045^{1/.25} = 2.5045^4$.  Seeing as we don't know what $x$ is taking the log of x doesn't get us closer and this seems a very round about  and obscure way to simply raise 2.5045 to the 4th power.

Comment: Good point. I guess its just overly complicated.

Comment: No.  It's always best to isolate the variable.  If the variable has a number added to it, then you subtract. If the variable is multiplied by a number then you divide.  If the variable is raised to a power then you raise it to the reciprical power.  If the variable it a base raised to the variable power *THEN* you take a log.  You always "strip" the variable by doing the inverse.  If you have $b^x$ then you take a log.  But if you have $x^b$ taking a log will get you nowhere.  $x^{.123489} = K$ is solved by .....

Comment: Yep, makes sense

Comment: $x = K ^{1/.123489}$. Taking log, $.123489 \log x = log K$ so $\log x = \log K^{1/.123489}$ so $x = 10^{\log K^{1/.123489}} = k^{1/.123489}$.  SO taking log was just an indirect waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example you can rewrite $x^{0.25}=x^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Then you can just put $x=2,5045^{\frac{4}{1}}$